# Don't delete emails from Exchange mailbox when deleted from phone

Tags: exchange-2010, iphone

Does anyone know if there is a way to make it so iPads/iPhones are able to download all emails but not delete them from the server, so that when you login to the desktop it downloads all of them exactly as it would if you didn't preview it on the phone?

I thought at first about using the iPhone with POP3, but this would also remove 80% of the functionality of exchange.

Comment: Why must they be deleted from the iPhone? Can't you just... I don't know.. not delete them from the phone? It sounds like you're using ActiveSync, in which case this is intended behaviour and I don't think you can change it (it wouldn't be much of a *sync* otherwise :P).

Comment: Does this fall under the guise of protecting users from themselves?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There isn't functionality in the ActiveSync protocol to allow for what you're talking about (limiting its ability to affect unread flags, delete items, etc). I suspect you're going to have a tough time finding what you're looking for.

You could do a "hack" by making a second mailbox for each phone user specified as an additional / alternate delivery recipient for their "primary" account and "point" the phone at that secondary mailbox. The advantage would be that changes they made in that "clone" mailbox wouldn't be reflected in their "primary" mailbox.

The disadvantage would be that changes they made in that "clone" mailbox wouldn't be reflected in their "primary" mailbox. Their "Sent Items" from the "clone" mailbox would be separate, as would be any other folders or items they create / file. It'd be a totally freestanding mailbox.

Comment: The reason i'm looking into this is, is because the CEO has requested this function so that they do not miss emails when they take a second and glance at them during meetings/off hours ect.

Comment: I know CEOs like to think the world orbits around them but some people need to learn that sometimes the world works the way that it works, not the way they would like it to work.

Comment: I have looked into this more because I wasn’t thinking of a way this would work. I was wondering if there was anything in the desktop synchronization that would do this. I know it requires an enterprise CAL.
I think this covers it pretty well. Thanks for all the work arounds!

Answer (score 2):

What I have done is set up a pop access to the mail box, where you can leave mail on server, then add an exchange account as well, in the exchange account turn off the mail process, but leave notes, calendar, task etc. Works great. A little lame but works